# Two domains pointing at same instance of Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to have one wordpress installation working on 3 different domains.
On server (shared hosting) I set up on 2 domains symlinks from public_html dir to the third one. Unfortunately it's working only on main domain.

I have also added:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
define('WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

To my wp-config but it didn't help. On the other domains I get blank page and 500 error code.

Comment: Why do you think it is a good idea to run exactly the same content on different domains?

Comment: If you want to run a different domain per language there are nice implementations in WPML / qTranslate.

Comment: @Blackbam it wasnt my idea, i just do the job, it have to be exactly same site

Answer (score 0):

The following discussion is dealing with exactly this problem: http://myjeeva.com/mapping-multiple-domains-into-single-instance-of-wordpress.html.

Check if WordPress address and site address are disabled in the backend and put the definitions at the correct location in wp-config.php (after the table_prefix line).

Note that you may have issues with Plugins (like Cache Plugins) which may lead to a 500 error (try with a naked WordPress installation first).

Note that having two domains for exactly the same site may cause SEO troubles and is definitly not a benefit in terms of SEO - your clients should know about that.